# Add an onclick attribute in code behind calling javascript function with string parameter referencing ClientID

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I've looked around, and I can't quite find all the pieces I need to put this together. The problem is that I want to call the same javascript function from multiple places, so I need to pass the element's ID into the function so I can change them all. The idea is very simple. I just want four checkboxes to call this function when clicked so that it will prevent the last box from being unchecked. Here's what I have so far.

HTML:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbBlue" Text="Blue" Checked="true" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbGreen" Text="Green" Checked="true" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbRed" Text="Red" Checked="true" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbYellow" Text="Yellow" Checked="true" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCheckCount" runat="server" Value="4" />
```

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cbBlue.Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkCheck(" + this.ClientID + ")");
    cbGreen.Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkCheck(" + this.ClientID + ")");
    cbRed.Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkCheck(" + this.ClientID + ")");
    cbYellow.Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkCheck(" + this.ClientID + ")");
}
```

Javascript:

```
function checkCheck(elementID) {
    if ($('#<%=hdnCheckCount.ClientID%>').val() == 1) {
        elementID.prop("checked", true);
        return;
    }
    else {
        if (elementID.is(":checked")) {
            elementID.prop("checked", false);
            $('#<%=hdnCheckCount.ClientID%>').val($('#<%=hdnCheckCount.ClientID%>').val() - 1);
        }
        else {
            elementID.prop("checked", true);
            $('#<%=hdnCheckCount.ClientID%>').val($('#<%=hdnCheckCount.ClientID%>').val() + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Am I close? Also, I'm a little unsure about whether I need to actually set the checked state of the boxes in the javascript, since I guess that's already handled elsewhere. But then I'm not sure about whether forcing it to true would work, since it might still be unchecked after the javascript function runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no data is actually being passed to the backend, I'd recommend doing this entirely in javascript. Since I see you are using jQuery this is what I'd recommend doing.

First off, add a class to all the checkboxes

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbBlue" CssClass="keepOneChecked" Text="Blue" Checked="true" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbGreen" CssClass="keepOneChecked" Text="Green" Checked="true" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbRed" CssClass="keepOneChecked" Text="Red" Checked="true" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbYellow" CssClass="keepOneChecked" Text="Yellow" Checked="true" runat="server" />
```

Then using jQuery to bind the onclick event

```
$(function(){ 
    //bind event
    $('.keepOneChecked').click(function(e){
        //get all the checkboxes that ARE checked
        //.keepOneChecked is applied to a span wrapping the input and label because of ASP
        var $checked = $('.keepOneChecked input:checked');
        if( $checked.length == 1){
            //if there is only 1, disable it so you can't uncheck it
            $checked.attr('disabled',true);
        }
        else{
            //otherwise a second or more just got checked so enable all of them
            $checked.attr('disabled',false);
        }
    }); 
});
```

As for the issue you are specifically having, I think when you are binding

```
cbRed.Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkCheck('#<%=this.ClientID%>')");
```

"this" is being refered to the page instead of the element, plus the syntax is wrong. You could try:

```
cbRed.Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkCheck('"+cbRed.ClientID+"')");
```

And see if that works, but I'd try doing it in only jQuery first.

Comment: This didn't work either. But we ended up abandoning this idea because we're writing a custom control that will replace the checkboxes. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly didn't work @JoeM ? Making a custom control like that is going to be a lot slower then doing it with javascript and then validating when they submit data. Every post back, especially in Forms is expensive.

Comment: It didn't prevent the last box from unchecking. I tried a few different ways and none worked. The custom control won't be using checkboxes anymore. It's going to be a modified drop down list.

Comment: @JoeM : take a look at this fiddle and compare it to what you have. I know your checkboxes will be asp control, but the principle remains the same

[https://jsfiddle.net/8w1pc7tk/](https://jsfiddle.net/8w1pc7tk/)

Basically the javascript I gave you shouldn't be in it's own function, but should just be included on the page somewhere or in a JS file that's included on the page.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work in the fiddle page, but it's not working for me with the ASP controls. I copy pasted the JS from here and from that link, and neither works. I can uncheck all four boxes.

Comment: @JoeM did you add 'CssClass = "keeponeChecked" ' to each checkbox? And you'll probably need to remove any other onclick event you have on there.

Comment: Yes to both. To be clear, I removed all the code related to this last Friday, then re-added just the code in your answer today in a second attempt.

Comment: @JoeM try my edited jQuery above, I forgot how ASP renders checkboxes wrapped in a span.