# How to Call Javascript function in asp:Radiobutton?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a Radio button in a Gridview and when we click on the button, i'm calling function in the code behind file(user control). Before that i need to implement need call a javascript function to confirm about change.  I tried onclick, OnClientClick, OnSelect and none of them worked as expected.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="ratiobuttonChoose" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                    OnCheckedChanged="Selected"/>
```

Can someone, please suggest me how to do this one.

Comment: I've read in SO that onclick works

Comment: It's not case sensitive is it? onClick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a script on Page_Load in code behind:

```
ratiobuttonChoose.Attributes.Add("onclick", "clientJsFunction()");
```

Reference: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f.aspx)

You can add onclick direct on your tag (VisualStudio don't suggest but it works):

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="ratiobuttonChoose" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
    OnCheckedChanged="Selected" onclick="alert('Clicked!');" />
```

You can also use jQuery, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809362/add-an-onclick-attribute-in-code-behind-calling-javascript-function-with-string).